# Spring MVC Security permitAll to / but denyAll to /** not working

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a Spring4 MVC application that is deployed on Wildfly10 and is configured using xml.

I have the following controller defined:

```
<mvc:view-controller path="/" view-name="/index" />
<mvc:view-controller path="/index" view-name="/index" />
```

And in Spring security define access:

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />
    ...
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="denyAll" />
    <form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard"
        always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
        authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
    <logout logout-success-url="/index" />
    <access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/> 
</http>
```

If I remove the denyAll to /** intercept-url the application works as intended however adding it causes security to redirect root calls to the login page and not the index page!

Is there a way I can have permitAll access to the root (Redirects to /index) of my application and still denyAll to /** thus covering anything else that is not defined?

Comment: Set `request-matcher="regex"` on `<http>` element, and try `/.+` as the pattern for the `denyAll` line.

Comment: Thanks @Vasan the `/.+` works 100%. I did not need to change the `request-matcher="regex"` at all, it must default to that.

Answer (score 0):

By Changing the pattern to `<intercept-url pattern="/.+" access="denyAll" />` as commented by Vasan got it working. below is an example of the change

```
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
<intercept-url pattern="/" access="permitAll" />
<intercept-url pattern="/index" access="permitAll" />
...
<intercept-url pattern="/.+" access="denyAll" />
<form-login login-page="/login" default-target-url="/dashboard"
    always-use-default-target="true" authentication-failure-url="/loginfailed"
    authentication-failure-handler-ref="authenticationFailureHandler" />
<logout logout-success-url="/index" />
<access-denied-handler ref="customAccessDeniedHandler"/>
```